# Vue.js shuffle components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making a cup game in Vue.js where there are N number of cups in line and one of them has a dice inside it.

```
<cup cupid="a" @onGameStateChange="onGameStateChange" ref="cup" />
<cup cupid="b" @onGameStateChange="onGameStateChange" ref="cup" />
<cup cupid="c" @onGameStateChange="onGameStateChange" ref="cup" />
```

I would now like to shuffle those cups to move any of the cups around the play field. Naturally it would mean that I have to move the DOM elements around.

But I seem to be a bit stuck on how I would achieve this in Vue.js. I tried attaching a ref (like above) to all of the cups and then getting the DOM element reference for all of the cups but now I'm a bit wondering how would I shuffle those around.

I also tried loading the cups from a data array in `v-for` and then shuffling the cups data property but visually it didn't seem to do anything. I also tried it through a compute property.

With Vue.js the fist rule is not to manipulate DOM directly, so how would I achieve this?

Comment: Shuffling with animation? Or just the order?

Comment: Candidly, Vue really isn't designed for gameplay. Its animations and general principles don't lend themselves well to game design. You want something dedicated to games, IMO, such as phaser, threejs, or similar. You might consider writing the game portion in one of these libraries, and embedding it in your Vue app.

Comment: You would need a [`key` attribute](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) for Vue to shuffle the DOM elements when you shuffle your data.

Answer (score 1):

Just think in MVVM way. Your game and three cups are just data, do not mix them up with DOM.

I write an example blow. Use an array to store cups. Use 'v-for' to generate DOM. Shuffle the Cups by "random sort" or "random an array index"!

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    cups: [{name: "cup1"}, {name: "cup2"}, {name: "cup3", imhere: true}]
  },
  methods: {
      shuffleCups() {
        this.cups.sort((a, b) => Math.random() > .5 ? -1 : 1);
      }
    },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    <button @click="shuffleCups">Shuffle</button>
    <div v-for="cup in cups"> {{ cup.name }}
      <span v-if="cup.imhere" style="color: red">*</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update: After written this snippet, I found [an example on vuejs.org](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions), it also shows "Transitions & Animation" effect.